# Where does the CSS style of <tr:table> come from?

Tags: css, jsf, trinidad

I have a Trinidad `<tr:table>`:

```
<tr:table id="searchTable1" value="#{bean.model.xlist}" var="arg" rows="10" 
    rowBandingInterval="1" varStatus="row" emptyText="#{xyzbundle.nofnd}">
```

I didn't specify any CSS style related attribute, however it generates a CSS-styled HTML table. Where does this CSS come from?

Comment: without giving cssStyle attribute how a style will be applied for a table.?

Comment: Please read http://www.cssbasics.com/introduction-to-css/. There are other ways than the JSF `cssStyle` attribute to style elements.

Comment: <tr:table id="searchTable1"
      value="#{bean.model.xlist}" rows="10"
      rowBandingInterval="1" var="arg" varStatus="row"
      emptyText="#{xyzbundle.nofnd}">

Comment: this is my table... but i cant find any styles.. for this.

Comment: As explained in the above linked tutorial you will have to look at the complete source of the html page as well as all the included stylesheets. The styling information that you are looking for is somewhere else than in the JSF tag.

Answer (score 1):

First of all read the guide for the trinidad skinning:
[Trinidad Skinning](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/devguide/skinning.html)

In your appropiate skinfile you can set several selectors like:

```
af|table
{
background-color: #F5F5DC;
border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
border-top: 1px solid #999999;
border-right: 1px solid #999999;
}
```

and many others.

Answer (score 0):

A tool like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) will help you to find the css file that defines the style. It might also be possible that the styling is defined within the header of the current page.

These two tutorials should help you to get started:

- http://getfirebug.com/css
- http://www.w3resource.com/web-development-tools/inspect-and-edit-HTML-and-CSS-with-Firebug.php

Alternatively the [developer tools of Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) and [Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg589507%28VS.85%29.aspx) will provide similar tools to inspect CSS.

Comment: Thank u Reto. Is there any other way to find. as we dont have access to add the plugin in my machine.

Comment: Well, then you will have to go trough the inline styles defined in the header as well as all the included css files by hand and find the lines that match the `tr` tag that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can create styles that apply to specific tags inside an tag with a id like:

```
#formID:searchTable1 tr {
   background: red;
}
```

This changes the background in all your tr tags inside the element with id=searchTable1 to red.

Please note that the default rendered id from jsf is constructed from id specified in `h:form` and the id from the tag.